# Programmatically theming CheckBox and RadioButton in android Lollipop bug

Tags: android, view, android-5.0-lollipop, tint

i'm working on a project where i have to programmatically theme checkboxes and radio buttons.

Everything works fine except for Lollipop where the states of the button become inverted only when i programmatically set said buttons checked

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JcrJ_vY1HnOXF6Yk4yT29ZUTA/view?usp=sharing

as you can see in the video (sorry for the quality), buttons work correctly when i click them, but when i set them programmatically with the "everything" button they freak out only on lollipop.

this is the tinting code

```
public static void setupCheckBox(AppCompatCheckBox checkBox) {

        int colorOn = getCurrentAccentColor();
        int colorOff = ContextCompat.getColor(checkBox.getContext(), R.color.grey);
        int colorDisabled = 0xFFAAAAAA;
        ColorStateList buttonStates = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[]{
                        colorOn,
                        colorDisabled,
                        colorOff
                }
        );
        checkBox.setSupportButtonTintList(buttonStates);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37084519#comment10

AppCompatRadioButton is not meant to be used like that. You're using a private API which is bound to break when not used correctly.

Use CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList().